# Processing 2.0 Movie cannot open movie file when running from jar

Tags: java, processing, executable-jar, movie, getresource

I'm trying to run a movie using the Processing 2.0 Movie class.

If I run my program from my code editor (Eclipse in my case) everything works fine and the code runs flawlessly: it locates and starts the movie.

However, when I export my program to a jar and start it from my terminal, it does locate the file but it crashes on trying to open it.

I am currently using this code to find my movie path string.

```
public String locateMovie(String moviePath) {
    String movie = MoviePlayer.class.getClassLoader().getResource(moviePath).getPath();
    if (movie == null) {
        System.out.println("FATAL ERROR --- Movie file not found: '" + moviePath + "'");
    }
    return movie;
}
```

As you can see I am using the classLoader to locate the file for me since the paths are different after I export it to a .jar file and do not wish to change the paths all the time myself. The .getPath() deletes the 'File:' in **File:**/Path/To/My/File as this is an unneeded side effect from using the above way.

A bit further in my code I've already added an extra check to see if nothing is wrong with the path that the classLoader is returning, I do this with the following lines.

```
File temp = new File(moviePath);
System.out.println("If I have something after this, the file exists: '" + temp + "'");
```

It always returns the right path, whether it's running from within my Eclipse (/Users/Path/To/My/Folder/2/java/Game/movies/introMovie.mp4) or from the executable .jar file (introMovie.mp4).

At first I thought it was strange that in the .jar file it was giving me a file straight away without the path leading to it because it does have some structure in my project but after using the

```
jar tf myProject.jar
```

command in my commandLine it returns the same file/pathname for the file so the path should be correct and all is still well here.

But now, when I try to load the movie via Processing' Movie class with the following code:

```
currentMovie = new Movie(parent, moviePath);
```

It throws an **java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException** exception and crashes. I have no idea what i'm doing wrong since this code runs flawlessly from within my code editor + I'm using the same way of locating files for my audio files and those run aswel, even from the executable .jar file.

As far as I can tell from reading the [Movie class reference library](http://processing.org/reference/libraries/video/Movie.html) it just needs a place to display it on and the path to the file which I am both giving.

I was hoping some veteran here could see what I am doing wrong and help me solve this problem that I'm been struggling with for a few days now. It's probably something stupid that I'm just overlooking right now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what's wrong but here's a couple things I would do:

check the permissions on the video file, make sure the program would have access to it.

I've read that it's a better idea to use

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
```

than the class's classloader, but I don't know if that would help.

Processing libraries are open source. Maybe see exactly where that exception is being thrown and take a look at the source. It might help you pinpoint the issue.